# The usage of "test"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-request

I wrote:

> We have developed a computer program for spelling training. In this program, a student takes **spelling tests** on a word list.

Actually the user spells some words using this program. Is each of these spellings a test? Is the whole session a test? Can it be used for either or both? What are other useful words in such a scenario?

Comment: The complement of "on" in this context is typically a subject or topic, or your knowledge thereof. We took a test on World War I.  You will be tested on your knowledge of calculus.  "A word list" doesn't quite qualify semantically as a subject, like geography, or binomials, or RNA, or qualify as knowledge in an area.  That's why "*on* a word list" doesn't work well here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We have developed a computer program for spelling training.
>   In this program, a student takes spelling tests **from** a word list.

The words to be spelled are **on** a list, and each one is taken **from** the list when the student is asked to spell it

**Tests** can be either big or small from single questions to hours long, which are then called **examinations** or **exams**.  Short tests may be called **quizzes** and usually only take a few minutes.  Teachers use them to ingrain lesson materials into students. If a quiz is given unannounced, it may be called a **pop quiz**.  **Exam** and **quiz** describe the relative lengths of a test.

The essence of **being tested** is to respond with the correct answer when asked a question.

Each of the questions is a **test** of knowledge, and the overall collection is also called a test if it functionally can be thought of as a single entity, usually on one topic of interest.  **Exams** are usually a collection of **tests** on several different topic and the process may last all day.  One **sits** an exam, but not a quiz.

Other words which might be used to express the same process are

> spelling **drills**
>   spelling **practice**
>   spelling **exercises**

Comment: Somewhat more "metaphorical", perhaps, but I'd be perfectly happy (perhaps even *more* so) with *taking spelling tests **against** a word list*.

Comment: Thank you but, "test" as I [saw](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/test_1) takes "on" preposition. *We have a test on irregular verbs tomorrow*, then why I can't use "on" here.

Comment: @Ahmad your example says "spelling tests (plural) from a word list (singular)". "A test **on** a word list" is the entire list, so you are saying the student would take multiple tests from the same list (maybe word order changes?). If each test has some different words than the previous test, then the whole word list is not used, and the ones that are used are taken **from** the word list. You could say "spelling tests **on** different word lists".

Comment: Tests can be **against** things such as "against the clock" which is a timed test. "spelling test **against** a word list" has the same meaning as using **on** but because **against** is a stronger word, has more emphasis on the word list.

Comment: How to differentiate the complete session with individual tests on each word? In another part I wrote *The procedure for doing a test on a word is as follows...*, Does emphasizing "on a word" make it distinct?

Comment: Also is it better to say "*The student takes spelling tests on words of a word list.*"

Comment: You could write: "Each session consists of individual word tests". You should still use **from a word list** in your second question, you could also use **from a vocabulary list**: "The student is asked to spell words from a (set) vocabulary list."

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much as you said, you can write:

> In this program, a student **spells words** on a word list

Don't use *test* since you say it is not really a test (just spelling some words does not qualify). A *test* has multiple questions and will be scored as a whole.

However, in an informal sense you could call it a *quiz*.

Comment: I don't think you can say it's not a "test" if a student is only asked to spell a single word. *"I'm really good at English!" "Says you! Let me give you a spelling test. Spell **amoeba.**" "A-M-O-E-B-A" "Okay, I agree you're good"* Sounds like a credible conversation to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I call that a *quiz*. As for [***test***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/test): "5. a set of questions, problems, or exercises for determining a person's knowledge, abilities, aptitude, or qualifications; examination"

Comment: We can all pick and choose from definitions of words with a range of meanings (the first two definitions in your link seem to be more about answering a *single* question, for example). As @Peter says above, *Tests can be either big or small from single questions to hours long*. And so far as your *quiz* alternative goes, [a single question quiz](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+single+question+quiz%22) gets only 6 Google Books hits, where [a single question test](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+single+question+test%22) gets 65. The words just aren't that "fixed".